# Зачем приводить объект к интерфейсному типу который реализован неявно, если в нем и так и так будут доступны методы интерфейса?

Tags: c#

Например:

```
List <int> list = new List<int>();
((IEnumerable<int>)list).GetEnumerator();
```

В первой строчке у объекта list будут доступны все поля и методы класса List, в том числе у него будут доступен метод интерфейса IEnumerable
Во второй строчке после приведения к типу IEnumerable у объекта полностью скрываются все поля и методы класса кроме метода , который реализуется от интерфейса IEnumerable.
В чем тогда смысл приводить к этому типу, если метод интерфейса доступен в первом и втором случае?
Скрывается только вся реализация класса, правда зачем ее скрывать мне тоже не очень понятно, подскажите кто-то, если поняли что я написал.
Просто увидел в одном проекте такие строчки кода и интересно зачем это нужно.

Comment: Конкретно этот кусок кода `((IEnumerable<int>)list).GetEnumerator();` смысла не имеет. Приведите реальный пример кода, по которому у вас вопросы.

Comment: IEnumerable <int> list = new List<int>();

Comment: Зачем скрывать поля и методы класса в данном случае?

Comment: это просто некорректно, называть переменную `list` и давать ей тип `IEnumerable<>`. Если эта переменная используется только в этом же методе и никуда не передается, никуда не добавляется, существует только для обхода по ней, то смысла так делать нет.

Comment: @tym32167, вообще-то имеет - тут будет боксинг энумератора внутри метода, а не снаружи. Только вот зачем, я ещё не придумал...

Comment: @Qwertiy `боксинг энумератора внутри метода` [как он тут будет](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vI3d.png) и зачем и почему это вообще имеет значение? )

Comment: @tym32167, а давай `IEnumerator<int> a = list.GetEnumerator();` и `IEnumerator<int> b = ((IEnumerable<int>)list).GetEnumerator();` и сравни результаты. А не с var. А вот зачем, я пока не придумал.

Comment: @Qwertiy А, теперь понял, там же методы разные. Но всё равно смысл этого не оч понятен :)

Comment: Думаю, этот код автосгенерирован, поэтому так.

Comment: Очень знакомая конструкция. ILSpy и DotPeak в таком виде представляют начало декомпилированного foreach. В последних версиях ILSpy нормально его сворачивает в большинстве случаев и даже лямбды переваривает, а DotPeak так и не научился нормально работать даже с foreach. А вообще по теме: интерфейс реализованный явно или неявно можно использовать для ограничения видимых членов класса в конкретном фрагменте кода или как наиболее общий тип для некоторого набора классов, реализующих данный интерфейс.

Comment: Конкретно в данном случае - незачем. И GetEnumerator и IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator (явная реализация интерфейса) делают одно и то же: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,569 (правда, первый возвращает структуру по значению). Но в общем случае они могут делать разное, так что речь не только о "скрытии". Вы выбираете, какой метод вызываете.